# How to fetch records from entity base on only Day and month?

Tags: 8, users, entities

How to fetch records from entity base on only Day and month

Like In DOB need to return those user which has current day and month.

E.g:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('field_dob', date('m-d'));
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

In anyone have idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried with $query->where();?

Comment: or with BEWTEEN?

Comment: Hi Robin, When I try to use "where", drupal throws error.

Comment: $query->where('field_dob', date('m-d')); used this

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: $query= \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
    ->condition('field_dob','%'.date('m-d').'%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute(); Try this

Comment: OMG! You made my day Shreya. Its working.

Comment: @ShreyaShetty I think that you should post your comment with some explanation as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are doing a LIKE query as the question stated that it wants to fetch record on basis of current month and day only not a year .

```
 $query= \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
     ->condition('field_dob','%'.date('m-d').'%', 'LIKE')
     ->execute()
```